# what is asp's Request.ServerVariables("AUTH_USER") jsp equivalent?

Tags: jsp, iis, authentication

well, on a IIS web site with integrated windows authentication and no anonymous access, I can retrieve the logon username of the user, something like like domain\user...

is it possible to achieve this with jsp on tomcat? (or any other container)

I've tried with request.getHeaderNames (on tomcat) but I only get

host, user-agent, accept, accept-language, accept-encoding, accept-charset, keep-alive, connection, cookie, pragma, cache-control

Hey, in asp and in php I get a lot more info!!! is there some way to enable that???

thanks a lot...

Answer (score 2):

You can use request.getHeader("AUTH_USER") or even request.getUserPrincipal() . This kind of information is independent from the language, it is a browser/server issue.